# No puedo actualizar el valor en una columna de una BD si ésta ya tiene un valor NULL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estoy intentando actualizar el valor de una columna de mi BD, donde ya existe un valor Null y no me lo permite sobreescribir ni actualizar.

Estoy utilizando laravel 10.

He probado eliminando el valor Null desde phpmyadmin por un valor de texto o numero tipo "Sin datos","0", etc, y ahí si, ejecuto el código y me permite actualizar esa celda de mi columna en la BD. Vuelvo a poner NULL, vuelvo a correr el código y no se actualiza.

¿Existe alguna restricción para actualizar los valores NULL en laravel o mysql?

Adj codigo:

```
public function updatePaquete($id, Request $request)
{
    $valores = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
   
        $registro = Rueddo::find($id);

    if ($registro) {
        // Mapeo de nombres de campos en el objeto JSON con nombres de columnas en la BD, para que por ejempplo: num_tracking_edit coloque los valores en la columna num_tracking
        $mapeoCampos = [
            'num_tracking_edit' => 'num_tracking',
            'idml_edit' => 'idml',
            'id_externo_edit' => 'id_externo',
            'direccion_edit' => 'direccion',
            'destinatario_edit' => 'destinatario',
            'cp_edit' => 'cp',
            'zona_edit' => 'zona',
            'referencias_edit' => 'referencias',
            'cliente_edit' => 'cliente_id',
            'provincia_edit' => 'provincia',
            'localidad_edit' => 'localidad',
            'telefono_edit' => 'telefono',
            'comentarios_edit' => 'comentarios',
        ];

        
        foreach ($valores as $nombreCampo => $valorCampo) {
            // Verificar si el campo existe en el mapeo
            if (array_key_exists($nombreCampo, $mapeoCampos) && $registro->offsetExists($mapeoCampos[$nombreCampo])) {
                // Actualizar el valor del campo en el modelo
                $registro->{$mapeoCampos[$nombreCampo]} = $valorCampo;
            }
        }

        $registro->save();

        
        return "Datos actualizados correctamente para el ID: $id";
    } else {
        
        return "Error: No se encontró el registro con ID: $id";
    }
}
```

---

Modelo de la tabla:

```
       <?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Rueddo extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_rueddo';
    protected $table = 'paquetes';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'num_tracking',
        'idml',
        'id_externo',
        'localidad',
        'direccion',
        'cp',
        'zona',
        'referencias',
        'destinatario',
        'cliente_id',
        'telefono',
        'provincia',
        'long',
        'lat',
        'id_chofer_sm',

    ];

    public function relaciones()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Relacion::class, 'id_rueddo');
    }

    public function cliente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class, 'cliente_id', 'id');
    }
    
}
```

---

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué estás intentando? ¿Arroja algún error?

Comment: Hola! el flujo es, traigo los datos de la DB, los que están en NUll, los muestro en el front como S/D. 

Por ejemplo quiero actualizar el Nombre y el Telefono. 
El nombre trae el dato "Pablo Gonzales", y el tel traer NUll, y lo muestro como S/D. 

Actualizo el nombre por "Pablo Perez"y el Telefono por "444444", corro el codigo, se guarda el nuevo nombre pero no el valor que asigné a telefono.
No muestra error y carga nuevamente la pantalla de forma correcta, mostrando el nombre actualizado pero no el telefono, que sigue siendo NULL en la BD.

Comment: Con gusto podríamos revisar cual es el problema, pero debes de compartir ya sea el query que ejecutas para hacer el update del valor en el campo "Telefono". Puedes también revisar esta respuesta que encontré y creo te puede ayudar. [How to update column with null value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870553/23537984)

Comment: Está muy bien que nos expliques el contexto, pero ¿y el código? Eso es lo que falla y eso es lo que queremos revisar para poder ayudarte. Sin ver el código no podremos ver dónde está el problema. Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código problemático.

Comment: Buen dia. Acabo de actualizar con el codigo. Gracias